# Get the content of a file located in /etc/something with PHP

Tags: php, file, printing, external

Is it possible to get the content of

```
/etc/asterisk/sip.conf
```

and print it with PHP ?

I'm trying that :

```
<?php
                $filecontents = file_get_contents("/etc/asterisk/sip.conf");
                print $filecontents;
?>
```

but it's not working ... The chmod on the file is correct.

Thank you

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: If this is Linux, isn't it supposed to be `/etc/` and not `/ect/` ?

Comment: yes, sorry for the mistake, the problem is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it's not working ... I set the rights.

Depending on what is not working you're likely setting the *wrong* rights.

Verify that by validating the return value:

```
$filecontents = file_get_contents("/ect/asterisk/sip.conf");
if ($filecontents === FALSE)
{
    echo "I made an error.\n";
}
else 
{
    print $filecontents;
}
```

Most likely your problem is `ect` which is variant of `etc` which does likely exists. To find out if a file exists or not, test it. The full code:

```
$file = "/ect/asterisk/sip.conf";

if (!is_file) {
    echo "The file $file does not exists. Please check the path.\n";
}

if (!is_readable) {
    echo "The file $file is not readable. Ensure you can read it.\n";
}

$filecontents = file_get_contents($file);
if ($filecontents === FALSE)
{
    echo "I made an error.\n";
}
else 
{
    print $filecontents;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I get this input :

Notice: Use of undefined constant is_file - assumed 'is_file' in /var/www/admin_siptrunks.php on line 42 Notice: Use of undefined constant is_readable - assumed 'is_readable' in /var/www/admin_siptrunks.php on line 46

Answer (score 2):

This primarily depends upon two major permissions, if your directory path mentioned is correct. You have mentioned '/ect' and I am afraid it might be a typo in your code.

1. The actual file permission of the file you are trying to access
2. The open_basedir restriction in your php directives configuration, and similar restriction from your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's your problem, but you wrote `/ect` , while the tradicional directory is `/etc`

Otherwise, put this right before the `file_get_contents`:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And check the error output

Comment: That integer isn't looking great enclosed in quotation marks :)

Comment: Yet it works. God bless loosely typed variables in PHP. `1=="1"==TRUE`, but `1!=="1"!==TRUE`

Comment: Yep it surely works, just that those quotes didn't belong there. It looks pro now :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm really sorry .. my sip.conf file was empty, I feel stupid

Comment: Yes, its quite stupid. However, the explanations aren't any less worthy. Best of luck in what you are working on. :)